# XML - For each node get attribute of parent node with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have his XPath issue that I have not been able to solve. I need a list of subtask name per element (6 outputs in total).

```
<task name="xx>
    <subtask name="tA">
        <element value="1"></element>
        <element value="2"></element>
        <element value="3"></element>
    </subtask>
    <subtask name="tB">
        <element value="4"></element>
        <element value="5"></element>
        <element value="6"></element>
    </subtask>
</task>
```

I have currently tried the following:

```
/task/subtask/element/../@name
```

This gives me below output:
tA; tB

However I need one output per element like this:
tA; tA; tA; tB; tB; tB

I'm going to use this in a Nintex workflow on SharePoint. Nintex is so 'cleverly' designed that I have to store all XML output variables seperately and thereafter insert them in e.g. a list. That is why I have to do 3 seperate XPath 'queries' each with the same number of 'records' to be able to consolidate the XML output in my SharePoint list:

1. Element values OK

   XPath: /task/subtask/element/@value

   Reault: 1;2;3;4;5;6
2. Subtask names HELP!

   XPath: /task/subtask/element/../@name  ???

   Reault: tA;tA;tA;tB;tB;tB
3. Task names HELP!

   XPath: /task/subtask/element/../../@name  ???

   Reault: xx;xx;xx;xx;xx;xx

Can this even be achieved with XPath? Or do I need to do something with XSLT?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be achievable using pure XPath 1.0. This is possible using XPath 2.0 or higher, or using XSLT

Comment: @har07 thanks for your input! I will try to see if I can solve the issue using XSLT.